# MySQL syntax to select table name from more than one choice that matches criteria

Tags: php, mysql

Question is how to dynamically build one statement to return just one table name from array `$tables` that has the most records that match criteria `$table.status = 'ready'`.

I already understand I *could* create a combined subquery and count each, then sort using small php function, but part of my mission is to use MySQL statement for the heavy lifting because I am assuming it will be faster.

For example,

```
$tables = array('foo','bar','beyond','repair') ;

// start building the statement
   $query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME" ;
          // ? What else add here $query .= '????' ;


// loop to build part of the statement
   foreach($tables as $table){
         // create this statement dynamically
         // somehow I need to incorporate count(*)
         // and $table.status = 'ready'
         // note: all tables in $tables have a column named 'status'
         // ? What else add here $query .= "????" ;
    }

// add any remaining syntax 
// ? What else add here $query .= "????" ;
```

And as stated in the question, I want to select based on the highest `count(*)` of rows where `$table.status = 'ready'`

(My server environment is PHP 5.3.29 and MySql 5.1.73-cll. )

I can already solve this with one query and some php but I am asking if there is an answer to just return the TABLE_NAME with the one statement.

For example, I can solve like this:

```
$choices = array() ;

$query = "SELECT";
    foreach($tables as $table) {
           // loop and create subqueries, append table name with _count and we will strip it later 
           $query .= "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table WHERE $table.status = 'ready') as ".$table."_count," ;
    }

$query = rtrim($query, ',');
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection,$query) or die("Sql error: " . mysqli_error($db_connection));
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            while (list($key, $val) = each($row)) {
                    $choices[ str_replace('_count', '', $key) ] = $val;
            }
    }
arsort($choices ); // sort by value  reverse
$table_with_highest_count = key($choices) ; // the key will be table name now
```

Again, it solves the question with one query but forces me into php to complete, thus the question I wrote above.

Comment: You could use mysqli or pdo to do a prepared statement and pass in the variables from your tables array.

Comment: Hi @trixtur, looking to return the specific TABLE_NAME from the list of choices I outlined in the array.  Looking for guidance on the *syntax* - how to write the statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you look here you can see how to pass in variables and how to do a prepared statement:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

It is important to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

```
$tables = array('foo','bar','beyond','repair') ;

$maxcount = 0;
$maxTableName = '';

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM :name WHERE status = 'ready'");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $table);

    $count = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($count > $maxCount) {
        $maxCount = $count;
        $maxTableName = $table;
    }
}

// Now $maxTableName is the one you are looking for.
```

Comment: Hi @trixtur, looking to return the specific TABLE_NAME from the list of choices I outlined in the array. Looking for guidance on the syntax - how to write the statement.  

Your answers is not returning TABLE_NAME, it is returning rows - not what is asked.  But thanks for effort so far.

Comment: I think I understand better... let me try again.

Comment: Nope.  I already have the tables I want to check in the array '$tables' I mentioned in the question.  I'd like one statement to do what I am asking in the question.  The statement must be a) built dynamically using the values from `$tables' and b) return just one TABLE_NAME that c) matches the criteria stated above - be the table with most ( highest COUNT() of $table.status = 'ready'.  All tables in that array have a column names 'status'.

Comment: @Marc was that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi, your attempt is valid, but it hits the database for the length of `$table`.  I can still do it in one query as I mentioned in the question using a combined subquery and grab the count of all tables in one query, then use php on the result to sort & return the result.  Before I decide to do that, I feel there is still a one query answer to return the TABLE_NAME for me and avoid running it through a php function.  Thanks for the effort so far.

Comment: You could join all of the tables together and use a case statement.